# Adding a dictionary into a dictionary in Python 3.2

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to create a dictionary inside a dictionary with one statement. If the key doesn't exist it should be created.

A code-snippet for what I have now:

```
self.data[self.stringvar1.get()] = { date : (int(self.total.get()), int(self.resources.get())) }
```

This doesn't create a new key, but overrides the self.data, even if stringvar1 was different. I've tried a few options and couldn't find what I want. Do I have to manually check if the key exists, or is there an easy idiom for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is to make `self.data` a `collections.defaultdict(dict)`.  Accessing non-existent keys on this `defaultdict` automatically creates a new dictionary for this key, and you can simply use

```
self.data[self.stringvar1.get()][date] = (
    int(self.total.get()), int(self.resources.get()))
```

Note that a `defaultdict` comes with the risk of hiding bugs, since you will never get a `KeyError`.  An alternative is to use a plain `dict` and the `setdefault()` method:

```
self.data.setdefault(self.stringvar1.get(), {})[date] = (
    int(self.total.get()), int(self.resources.get()))
```

Comment: This fails when the stringvar1.get() -key hasn't been created.

Comment: Setdefault method works like a charm. Yet to check out what collections would do overall, but I believe I have the solution.

Answer (score 0):

This is more of an idea than an answer (maybe I can't add comments because I'm a 'new' user).

To merge dictionaries you might try doing something like:

```
var = dict(dict1.items() + dict2.items())
```

As for adding the key if it doesn't exist, you might want to check:

```
setdefault(key[, default])
If key is in the dictionary, return its value. If not, insert key with a value of default and return default. default defaults to None.
```